# how to disable to execute MySQL event at creation of it

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, scheduler, mysql-event

At the execution of MySQL event by default it will executes query which is inside MySQL event.

I want to disable it to execute query at creation.

```
$this->db->insert("invoice", $data);
$last = $this->db->insert_id();
$str = $this->db->last_query();
$this->db->query("SET GLOBAL event_scheduler =  'OFF'");
$schedule = $this->db->query("CREATE EVENT Recurrence".$last." ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MONTH ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE DO $str");
        $this->db->query("SET GLOBAL event_scheduler =  'ON'");
```

Comment: YOUR QUESTION IS NOT CLEAR AT ALL?

Comment: when MySQL event is created at that time two entries are inserted in invoice table that i want to stop

Comment: either comment your top third lines or move them after event creation code.

Comment: still two entries in the table